# Looping Through Multidimensional Array with Nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

I have simple JS(jquery) code and I would like to run it **through all three nested arrays.**
Now it **only executes first nested array ([16, 10, 11) and then stops**.
I have read that "for" loop may work, but I tried and failed :[

Is any1 capable of solving this problem? I will be grateful!

```
$(function(){ 
    var cat = [[16, 10, 11],[15, 10, 11],[36, 10, 11]];
    $('li#hcategory_' + cat[0][0] + ' ul.level2 > li:gt(' + cat[0][1] +')').hide();
      var l = $('li#hcategory_' + cat[0][0] + ' .level2 > li').length;
      if (l > cat[0][2]) {
          $('li#hcategory_' + cat[0][0] + 'span.show_more_button').show();
      } else {
          $('li#hcategory_' + cat[0][0] + 'span.show_more_button').hide();
      }
      $('li#hcategory_16 .show_more_button').click(function () {
        $('li#hcategory_' + cat[0][0] + ' ul.level2 > li:gt(' + cat[0][1] +')').show('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for iterating.

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

```
$(function () {
    var cat = [[16, 10, 11], [15, 10, 11], [36, 10, 11]];
    cat.forEach(function (c) {
        $('li#hcategory_' + c[0] + ' ul.level2 > li:gt(' + c[1] + ')').hide();
        var l = $('li#hcategory_' + c[0] + ' .level2 > li').length;
        if (l > c[2]) {
            $('li#hcategory_' + c[0] + 'span.show_more_button').show();
        } else {
            $('li#hcategory_' + c[0] + 'span.show_more_button').hide();
        }
        $('li#hcategory_16 .show_more_button').click(function () {
            $('li#hcategory_' + c[0] + ' ul.level2 > li:gt(' + c[1] + ')').show('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great.
I just had to change line 10th into:
$('li#hcategory_' + c[0] + ' .show_more_button').click(function () {

It was my fault because I forgot to remove "16" from there :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double nested `forEach()` method first for the main array and the second for each nested array like such:

```
var cat = [[16, 10, 11],[15, 10, 11],[36, 10, 11]];

 cat.forEach(function(v,i){
     //here v represents the values of the first level,
     //assuming it contains only arrays you can run a nested 
     console.log(v);
     v.forEach(function(vv, ii){
         // here you can access booth arrays respectively calling them
     console.log(v);
     conosole.log(vv);
     });
});
```